# Drawbacks of building a background-only COCOA app as a launch daemon?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Are there any drawbacks of building a background-only COCOA app without any GUI and run it as a launch daemon. This would use:

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

The primary advantage of using this and not building a objective-C command line tool is that It offers an implicit run-loop with benefits including well defined callbacks when application finishes launch or during termination. This would need to be explicitly implemented in a command line app.

Are there any disadvantages such as functionality break? Will the launch of the daemon be deferred?

Comment: If it's background-only then why do you need Cocoa?

Comment: because I am using NSApplicationDelegate which relies on AppKit

Comment: You don't need that.  I wrote [RunLoopController](https://github.com/trojanfoe/RunLoopController) which allows you do use Objective-C/Foundation in a command line utility (which could easily be modified to a daemon).

Comment: ok, but is there any disadvantage of using NSApplicationDelegate and Cocoa framework for launchdaemon as it makes things pretty streamlined and straightforward. This was the primary question.

Comment: Well you are using a tiny piece of a very large framework.  If you want to use Foundation classes then you need a runloop (and that's where RunLoopController comes in) and any other facility of `NSApplicationDelegate` can be easily replaced with your own code (see some of the examples bundled with RunLoopController for deciding when to terminate, for example).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "launch daemon"? Do you mean a [daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION2) which runs outside of a user login context? Or do you mean an [agent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION3), which runs within a user login context?

Comment: @Ken, I mean a daemon that runs in root context.

Comment: @Trojanfoe, I'll give a try. Out of curiosity, Even if we use AppKit in a launch daemon, how adversely would it affect the functionality of the program

Comment: @Anil Probably nothing at all; you'd have to try.  However it is possible it will attempt to connect to the window server as using it implies the use of the screen.  I am not certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a daemon, there are serious drawbacks to using any non-daemon-safe framework. From [Technical Note TN2083: Daemons and Agents – Layered Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION23):

> ### Layered Frameworks
>
> Most Mac OS X functionality is implemented by large system frameworks.
>   Many of these frameworks use Mach-based services that they look up
>   using the bootstrap service. This can cause all sorts of problems if
>   you call them from a program which references the wrong bootstrap
>   namespace.
>
> Apple's solution to this problem is layering: we divide our frameworks
>   into layers, and decide, for each layer, whether that layer supports
>   operations in the global bootstrap namespace. The basic rule is that
>   everything in CoreServices and below (including System, IOKit, System
>   Configuration, Foundation) should work in any bootstrap namespace
>   (these are **daemon-safe frameworks**), whereas everything above
>   CoreServices (including ApplicationServices, Carbon, and AppKit)
>   requires a GUI per-session bootstrap namespace. …
>
> In summary, the concrete recommendations are:
>
> - When writing a daemon, only link to daemon-safe frameworks (see [Framework Cross Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION24)).
> - When writing a GUI agent, you can link with any framework.
> - If you're writing a daemon and you must link with a framework that's not daemon-safe, consider splitting your code into a daemon
>     component and an agent component. If that's not possible, be aware of
>     the potential issues associated with linking a daemon to unsafe
>     frameworks (as described in the next section).
>
> ### Living Dangerously
>
> If your daemon uses frameworks that aren't daemon-safe, you can run
>   into a variety of problems.
>
> - Some frameworks fail at load time. That is, the framework has an initialization routine that assumes it's running in a per-session
>     context and fails if it's not.
>
>   This problem is rare on current systems because most frameworks are initialized lazily.
> - If the framework doesn't fail at load time, you may still encounter problems as you call various routines from that framework.
>
>   - A routine might fail benignly. For example, the routine might fail silently, or print a message to stderr, or perhaps return a
>       meaningful error code.
>   - A routine might fail hostilely. For example, it's quite common for the GUI frameworks to call abort if they're run by a daemon!
>   - A routine might work even though its framework is not officially daemon-safe.
>   - A routine might behave differently depending on its input parameters. For example, an image decompression routine might work for
>       some types of images and fail for others.
> - The behavior of any given framework, and the routines within that framework, can change from release-to-release.
>
> The upshot of this is that, if your daemon links with a framework
>   that's not daemon-safe, you can't predict how it will behave in
>   general. It might work on your machine, but fail on some other user's
>   machine, or fail on a future system release, or fail for different
>   input data. You are living dangerously!

Read the whole technote for the full details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you please point to the documentation that list the frameworks which are daemon safe?  Where is this:(see Framework Cross Reference)?

Comment: It immediately follows the part of the document I linked to and quoted, but I'll edit with a link.